# How to mix SSR and static content generation in NuxtJS 3?

Tags: vue.js, nuxt.js, nuxtjs3

I read since some month that NuxtJs 3 will bring a new Nitro engine able to handle both SSR and static generation.

I am unable to find any kind of document, tutorial, video or any about this feature.

But it is really what we need

Imagine to be able to do SSR of a catalogue of products having the single datasheet page, very very intensive to generate and always static in our case, be statically generated.

How can we realize it?

Briefly, how to use both SSR and static and in which sense can we use both with nitro? Which limits and what problema can lead to?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're looking for this one: https://github.com/nuxt/framework/discussions/560#discussion-3589420

This is planned, no date yet and pretty much what you need. Expect it maybe by the end of the summer.

It should not lead any particular problem.